# Justify the limit of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

I've showed these two equalities:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n}r^n=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$

and
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sin(n\theta)}{n}r^n=\arctan\frac{r\sin\theta}{1-r\cos\theta}$.

Now I would like to justify going to the limit $r\rightarrow 1^{-}$, but in fact, a I haven't got basic analysis for a while now and have bit difficulties ^^. Please, give a hint. I suppose some boundness kind of argument would make a job, but..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Abel's theorem guarantees (for a power series with radius of convergence 1) that

$$\lim_{r \to 1-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \cos (n \theta)}{n}r^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \cos (n \theta)}{n},$$

if the series on the RHS converges.

Convergence, for $\theta \neq 2m\pi$, follows from the Dirichlet test since $1/n$ is decreasing and convergent to $0$ and the partial sums

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(k \theta)$$

are bounded for all $n$.

Note that

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(k \theta)\right| = \left|\frac{\sin(n \theta/2)\cos[(n+1)\theta/2]}{\sin(\theta/2)}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{|\sin(\theta/2)|}.$$